# Is it possible to display custom/dynamic info on the Github Workflow Summary view?

Tags: github, github-actions

Do Github Actions provide a way to append values to job names, display workflow summary, or write values anywhere on summary view?

My goal is to have quick glance at results and avoid opening jobs to view the values in echo steps or raw logs.

Please see the example below where I demonstrated values that I already have available in my workflow outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution I could find is [Adding a Job Summary](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-job-summary) section to the workflow run view. Summary content is generated at run and can show values produced by the workflow which is exactly what I wanted.

**Workflow step**

```
      # Set Job Summary
      - name: Set Job Summary
        run: |
          echo "### ${{inputs.environment}} tested! " >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

**Result** (notice how it appeared below all other sections)
[image]

Here's a detailed example from [github.blog](https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/), only down side of this approach is that the summary section is appended to the bottom of the page, and will apear below error and warning blocks thus you will need to scroll down to view the custom summary.